# Expecting all array elements to match single value regardless of size using chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, chai

Considering an array `[1, 1, 1]` how can I validate that all elements matches `1` using chai.js?
Is there something like `expect(array).to.only.contain(1);`?

Comment: I mean you could loop through the array.

Comment: There are several ways to do it, wanted to figure maybe someone knows specific one-line solution using chai. Using array would basically throw exception on first mismatch and I want to make sure that all element where assessed.

Comment: I understand but i thought you wanted all elements to be 1. So if it finds a mismatch the you would want it to through an exception right?

Comment: Here is something you can try: 
```let t;
    array.map(a => (a === 1 ? (t = true) : (t = false)));
    console.log(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way I do it for elements in array is to go through each element and check that value:

```
array.forEach(el => expect(el).toBe(1));
```